# Got exception when deserialise xml data

Tags: c++, boost, c++17

I got this exception : **"libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::archive::archive_exception: input stream error-No such process
terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::archive::archive_exception: input stream error-No such process
(lldb) "** in my program when deserialize from xml file.

My program :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include<boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>

int main(){
    std::string fname = "file.xml";

{
    std::string a("hello world");
    
    std::ofstream of(fname.c_str());
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive of_xml(of);
    of_xml << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a);
    
    of.close();
    
}

{
    std::string b;
    std::ifstream inf(fname.c_str());
    boost::archive::xml_iarchive inf_xml(inf);
    inf_xml >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(b);
    
    inf.close();
    
    std::cout<<"string is : "<<b<<"\n";
}


return 0;
}
```

How to handle this exception guys?

Comment: At which line of the above code you got the exception? You handle exception by using try/catch? What is the problem with that?

Comment: the line " inf_xml >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(b); " gives exception and when I uses try-catch block the exception not caught by block, I'm using Xcode and don't known why it's giving me this error

Comment: Unrelated: You don't need `.c_str()` when opening the file streams - and file streams will be closed automatically when they go out of scope.

Comment: With [this slightly modified program](https://pastebin.com/5tMmj3UX) that I compiled with clang++ I get this [AddressSanitizer](https://pastebin.com/HBKMjWT9) output. If I compile with g++ the same program seems to work. I started running the g++ version in valgrind, but it just keeps on running... It's been going on for 30+ minutes now.

Comment: @TedLyngmo interesting, with g++10 and clang++9 (asan/ubsan enabled) it runs fine on my box (boost 1.74.0) (note they use different versions of the sanitizer libs).

Comment: Same with optimized builds, and using valgrind on the g++ build.

Comment: My best bet is that your setup is broken (using incompatible shared libraries vs. the version at compile time) and/or you're not actually reading the file you think you are (is the file actually written? are there permission errors?)

Comment: @sehe Odd indeed. I may have thrown in too many libraries in the mix (my default stackoverflow makefile links will all libraries I've ever seen here :-) ). The boost version I used was the latest commit on the `develop` branch (1.75-ish), so not entirely stable perhaps. I just tried compiling again and now both the g++ (10.2.1) and clang++ (10.0.1) versions barf. The clang version on one of the boost python libs... Hmm, need to narrow down the library list somehow :)

Comment: [OffTopic]@TedLyngmo Hah. We have similar workflows. I carry a loooong list of dependencies which I sometimes forget to comment out (e.g. today I had to comment armadillo again for it to compile with clang due to some other missing DSO :))[/OffTopic]